# How can I have pinch zoom and two-finger rotation at the same time on an UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an Image View and I need to be able to pinch-zoom it, scroll it when it is zoomed and also rotate it with two-finger.

Initially I used a scrollView and added ImageView to it. but ImageView wasnt getting rotation gestures as ScrollView was intercepting them.

So I added the gesture to the ScrollView started rotating the scrollView itself.

Things work fine but rotated scrollView doesn't look good.

So I made the ScrollView get the rotation gesture but rotated the imageView in it instead of ScrollView.

But Now, the problem is If I rotate the image and then zoom and again try to rotate, previous rotation is lost and same when I rotate the previous zoom level is lost.

How should I go about it ? Is the scrollView unnecessary ?